# Vigenere decryption and modulo

Tags: algorithm, performance, vigenere

I was looking at the Vigenère encryption/decryption algorithm on Wikipedia, and I'm wondering which approach is the most efficient/correct between:

`return a % b`

and:

```
if a < 0    
    return a += b
else 
    return a
```

when:
`-b <= a <= b`

Or maybe it is equivalent once compiled?

Thank you for enlighten me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this nano-optimization is of little interest, as you need texts long by million characters before there is any percievable difference.

Both the modulo operation and conditional branches are "costly" compared to other operations, and they are quite processor architecture dependent. So the only way to know is to benchmark, taking sufficient care to be in realistic conditions yet get reproducible results (which is a little contradictory).

This said, be aware that % does not implement a true modulo operation for negative arguments and you will get wrong results if you assume so.

Comment: Okay, anyway i was not looking for optimisation as I'm aware that it would only have a very small impact on my code.
But what you said about the `%` implementation is what I was expecting. So it obviously depends on the language. I tried in  Haskell and `%` seems to produce the expected result but I will keep the `if statement`
Thank you :)

Comment: @MathersMax: alternatively, `(a + c) % b` will work, where `c` is a well-chosen constant.